# Stuck on java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 when trying to read a textfile into a binary tree

Tags: java

I am trying to read a text file into a binary tree by using delimiters to separate the different fields. When I try to read it into the binary tree I get the array out of bounds erropackage Hospital;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;`

public class main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patient.txt"));
        String line;

        BinaryTree hospital = new BinaryTree();

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[]text = line.split(",");
            hospital.insert(text[0], text[1], text[2], text[3], text[4]);
        }
        in.close();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: check the length of `text` before insert

Comment: You should post your `patient.txt` file here. It is very hard to tell otherwise.

Comment: @Teemo Edit your question and include the text file.

Comment: looks like you don't have 4 commas in the line

Comment: some elements specially the last date colums are empty so as i said before check for `text` length before `insert()`, also note `insert()` should be defined with `String... s` to deal with varying length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your split code with code below. If you don't use limit parameter, by default, split method eliminates the  trailing empty elements. With `-1` parameter this problem will be solved.

```
String[] text = line.split(",", -1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now!

Comment: @Teemo It looks like that you do not have text after the fourth comma in your text file at some of the places. This problem can be solved by this.

Comment: "by default, split method eliminates empty elements." is not correct. `split` doesn't remove any empty elements, but only trailing ones. Empty elements in the middle or at start are not removed.

Comment: Yes you are right, my memory mislead me. Thanks for the correction.